# Formatting scale bar text with thousands separator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale-bar

I wonder if this is possible. I want to show the text (numbers) of the scale bar in Print Composer with a thousand separator in order to make the labels more readable. All I can do for now is change the font and color. I can not find an option similar to the grid labels, where you can define a custom setting for the label and use format_number(@grid_number,0 for instance. I am using QGIS 2.18 in Win 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In QGIS 3.14, we can customize the number format of the scale bar, including the thousand and the decimal separator:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I wanted the same and I could not do it, so I found this other way that allow us to change the units. In my case from meters to kilometers. The final results fitted my needs at least.

[image]